# When add service reference project references are added

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services

We got a problem when add a webservice reference to a project with Visual Studio option "Add Service reference". When the generation of client of web service is ended, two or three references to dll are added in project. The references to projects already exists, but Visual Studio add anothers to Dlls.

If the developers don't remove this references, many times exists compilation problems or very rare issues when the application runs. Exists some ways for auto delete this references when the code generation is ended? I think this references are needed for svcutil for "reuse types" option but not sense remains when webservice client has finalize generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the reference of the DLL(s) you have in your project has a different version from the one used in the WebService. That's why a second reference is automatically added.

The project won't compile at this point due to the ambiguous namespaces/methods in the different versions of the same DLL.
Removing one of the references is not a solution of the problem.

You should use the same DLL version in your project and in the WebService.

Also, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) article might be useful as guidelines on how to manage project references.